# user foreign key in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have one user model and Accesskey model. I want to save user who is accessing the API(access_key) in the accesskey table.

**models.py**

```
class AccessKeys(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user',null=True)
    access_keys =models.CharField(max_length=400)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.access_keys
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AccessKeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.RelatedField(source='CustomUser', read_only=True)
    access_keys = serializers.CharField(max_length=200,required=True)
    class Meta:
        model =AccessKeys
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class AccessKeyView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    queryset = AccessKeys.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccessKeySerializer

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when I'm saving accesskey in the model there is null value in user_id field.

Comment: ```serializer.save(user=request.user)```

Comment: @token  **Views.py**
  `  serializer = AccessKeySerializer(request.user)
     Key = serializer.data.get('access_keys')`
when I'm running this I'm getting error-

AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'
Could you please resolve this. I'm trying but couldn't fix it.